# What calculation is being done behind below R code

Tags: r

I know, it is quite silly but I am unable to find out the calculation behind this code

```
num = 11
num %% 2:(num-1)
```

Above code gives the result as,

```
# 1 2 3 1 5 4 3 2 1
```

How does the calculation work behind this?

Comment: Translated to English, it's something like "the remainder when 11 is divided by each of 2, 3, 4, ..., 9, 10"

Comment: Picked up your hint Marius, Thanks!
11%%2
11%%3
11%%4
11%%5
11%%6
11%%7
11%%8
11%%9
11%%10
I thought the calculation was num%%2 first and then num-1

Answer (score 1):

Operator `%%` divides the number in front by the number in back of it as many times as it can and returns the left over value.

For example:

```
11 %% 2
[1] 1
```

In your code, `2:(num-1)`  creates a vector of integer numbers from 2 to 10:

```
2:(num-1)
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Then, the code apply operator `%%` on `num` and above vector. So, we expect the result would be the remainders when `num` is divided by each element of the vector:

```
num %% 2:(num-1)
[1] 1 2 3 1 5 4 3 2 1
```